# ESLint Parsing Error - Unexpected token for a predefined variable

Tags: javascript, eslint

ESLint is giving the error `Parsing error: Unexpected token Occupations` when I try to check this script.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Discord = require('discord');

const { occupations: occupationsList } = require('./data/occupations.js');

const Users = sequelize.import('models/Users');
const Occupations = sequelize.import('models/Occupations');

// Add a new user to the cache and database
cache.newUser = async (id) => {
    const user = await Users.create({
        foo: 'bar',
    });
    console.log('New user created');

    // Create professions for the new user
    const occupations_ = new Discord.Collections();
    occupationsList.forEach(occ => {
        const newOcc = await Occupations.create({  // Parsing Error: Unexpected token Occupations
            foo: 'bar',
        });
        occupations_.set(occ.name, newOcc);
    });

    // Add values to cache
    this.set(id, {
        user: user,
        occupations: occupations_,
        buffs: {},
    });
    console.log('New user added to cache');
};
```

As I'm trying to point out, I have both `Users` and `Occupations` objects, but only `Occupations` is causing this error. In addition, the error disappears if I move the statement causing the error out of that block. Is there some limit on the number of blocks deep to which ESLint can find defined tokens?

The eslintrc I'm using:

```
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
}
```

Comment: I get the error “Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function”, when I change the script type to “module”. The `forEach` callback isn’t an async function, so `await` cannot be used in there.

Comment: Ah, that does indeed fix the problem. Can you post it as the answer so that I can accept it? Can you also mention the ESLint config you're using, as your error message was clearly more helpful than mine.

Comment: What exactly fixed the problem?

Comment: I didn't realize that the async property doesn't carry over to callback functions defined inside an async function.
I fixed it by changing that map.forEach() iterator to a normal for loop that iterates over the elements instead.